# Turn off token burn after x-amount of coins are reached?

Tags: burn

Say if I have a token like safemoon. Is there a way to add in a function to turn off token transaction burn fee once x-amount of tokens are in circulation?

I’m newer to solidity, and I want to be sure I’m going in the right direction, but as of now I have no leads for implementing this function.

Answer (score 0):

Well to make it simple;

You would need a point in time to stop the mint.

It could be anything, let's take a look at the supply.

You have a function that returns the total supply.
You have a function that burn tokens.

Here is a minimalist example where the burn function would return and not execute the burn is a target limit is reached.

```
uint256 threshold;  // max supply target

function burn(uint256 amount) public {
 if(totalSupply() >= threshold){
  return;
 }

  // burn here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So I would not need to create a new variable in this sense for tokens burned? Something like what you described above should suffice for turning off the burn fee? I just want to make sure I’m fully understanding it before I deploy to testnet to try it out.